# is there any alternative to event sourcing in microservices arcitechure implementation? please suggest

Tags: microservices

Normally for maintianing atomicity we use event sourcing concept in microservices . Are there alternative approach/approaches to solve this data consistency issue  without using event sourcing frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

The first and best way to maintain consistency in you microservices is to organize them in a way that each microservice manages its own data only.

Event sourcing may be a way for managing distributed data among several services. Several patterns exist, with no silver bullet.

The topic is too large for here, but I wanted to give you clues about the down votes on your question.